# C# DataGridView retrieving outdated results from database when Child Form is closed

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have a form opens up a **dialog** that contains a DataGridView.

When I double click the DataGridView, it opens up a child form that contains details of that row.

Once I save any updates, the child form closes and the DataGridView should be refreshed.

However, I have noticed that the DataGridView's refresh function is not getting the right data back from the database. It is getting the data from BEFORE the update and not AFTER the update thus displaying incorrect data.

I am unsure of how to continue on from here as my current method is to refresh the DataGridView directly from the Child Form

Here is my Code

This is the double click action to open the child form

```
private void fieldsDataGridView_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in fieldsDataGridView.SelectedRows)
    {
        fieldIdInput.Text = row.Cells["Id"].Value.ToString();
        DialogResult dr = new DialogResult();
        EditFields editFields = new EditFields(this,programIdInput.Text, fieldIdInput.Text, false);
        editFields.Show();
    }
}
```

This is the Refresh function contained on the first form

```
public void RefreshDataGrid()
{
    var selected = programInput.SelectedValue;
    if (selected != null)
    {
        var result = programsData.Get(selected.ToString());
        if (result != null)
        {
            programIdInput.Text = result.Id;
            LoadList(result.Id);
        }
    }
    if (selected == "-1")
    {
        RecursiveClearInputs(this.Controls);
        programIdInput.Text = "";
        fieldIdInput.Text = "";
        fieldsDataGridView.DataSource = null;
    }
    fieldsDataGridView.Refresh();
    fieldsDataGridView.ClearSelection();
}

private void LoadList(string Input)
{
    fieldsDataGridView.DataSource = null;
    List<Field> fields = new List<Field>();
    fields = fieldsData.GetAllByTaskId(Input);
    List<FieldsDGViewModel> fdgvm = new List<FieldsDGViewModel>();
    foreach (var item in fields)
    {
        var f = new FieldsDGViewModel
        {
            Id = item.Id,
            Name = item.Name,
            Order = item.Order,
            IsPrint = item.IsPrint
        };
        fdgvm.Add(f);
    }
    fdgvm = fdgvm.OrderBy(x => x.Order).ToList();
    fieldsDataGridView.DataSource = fdgvm;
    fieldsDataGridView.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
    fieldsDataGridView.Columns["Id"].Visible = false;
    fieldsDataGridView.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells);
}
```

This is the child forms constructor

```
private string ProgramId;
private string FieldId;
private bool IsNew;
private Fields Field;
ProgramsData programsData = new ProgramsData();
FieldsData fieldsData = new FieldsData();
PrinterData printerData = new PrinterData();

public EditFields(Fields Field, string ProgramId, string FieldId, bool IsNew)
{
    this.ProgramId = ProgramId;
    this.FieldId = FieldId;
    this.IsNew = IsNew;
    this.Field = Field;
    InitializeComponent();
    this.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(this.EditFields_FormClosing);
}
```

This is the Child Forms closing function

```
private void EditFields_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    Field.RefreshDataGrid();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the data is saved successfully from the Child Form? Are you able to see the data updated in the database?

Comment: Yes. When I close the form with the DataGridView and open it again, the correct data is displayed. It sounds like a thread or cache issue but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Did you debug the code of  `RefreshDataGrid ` and `GetAllByTaskId` method? Are you changing `ProgramId` too in the 'ChildForm` ?

Comment: Yes I debugged it. Nope. I'm not changing ProgramId in the ChildForm. ProgramId is just used to store in the db

Comment: From the logic of method `RefreshDataGrid` it looks like `selected` is not null it is also not `-1`. Which skips both the `if` blocks and that causes no data refresh to happen in GridView. Did you check what values you are getting in `selected` variable and also what value you are getting in `result` variable?

Comment: There is a hidden input textbox on the form with the DataGridView. When an item is selected on the DataGridView, the inputbox is populated. So no matter what, the selected will not be null.

Comment: `fieldIdInput` and `programInput` are the same? Only you can debug the code and verify what values you are getting in `selected` and `result`.

Comment: Nope. ProgramInput is different. FieldIdInput is the Id for the selected item on the row of the DataGridView Table. I havae just debugged it. In result, I get the old values and in selected it is the same ProgramId that was selected before the ChildForm opened.

Comment: I am not sure what the problem could be, however, I recommend you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Playing this question-answer back and forth is a huge waste of time. Do yourself and others a favor and create a MCVE. I am confident that this process will most likely reveal your issue. In addition, posting “incomplete” code and “code that will not compile” and more importantly, code that “does not reproduce the problem” will most likely be avoided by others. Thus, reducing you chances of getting help.